# Strategy for interleaving jobs on AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, architecture

Let's say I have 1000's of jobs to perform repeatedly, how would you propose I architect my system on Google AppEngine?

I need to be able to add more jobs whilst effectively scaling the system. Scheduled Tasks are part of the solution of course as well as Task Queues but I am looking for more insights has to best utilize these resources.

**NOTE**: There are no dependencies between "jobs".

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are there dependencies between these jobs ? Time required to run ?

Comment: In GAE, each scheduled task is limited to ~30secs. I expect each of my "job" to be << 30secs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what little description you've provided, it's hard to say. You probably want to use the [Task Queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/), and maybe the [deferred library](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html) if you're using Python. All that's required to use these is to use the API to enqueue a task.

If you're talking about having many repeating tasks, you have a couple of options:

- Start off the first task on the task queue manually, and use 'chaining' to have each invocation queue the next one with the appropriate interval.
- Store each schedule in the datastore. Have a cron job regularly scan for any tasks that have reached their ETA; fire off a task queue task for each, updating the ETA for the next run.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [Cron Jobs](http://code.google.com/intl/ca/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html).

Regards.

Comment: yes scheduled tasks are part of the solution but I am looking for a little more architectural level suggestions.

Comment: And what is the "architectural level" problem?

Comment: If you want to bypass the 30 secs limit you can create a dummy JSP that make AJAX calls to a RESTful "task" (I mean interruptible and restartable)